# Excel: Can I create a Formula based on the Color of a Cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm a beginner and trying to create a formula that modifies the contents of Cells of Column J based on the color of the cells in correspondent rows, I mean:

If Cell F7 is yellow then display 0 in Cell J7.

If Cell G7 is yellow  then display 1 in Cell J7.

If Cell H7 is yellow  then display 2 in Cell J7.

This is conditional based on the cell fill color.

I've already tried to use a some a new Name Manager =GET.CELL(6,Sheet1!F7) and then the formula =IF(CellColor=6;"1";"") -> the false value is working however the true one is not.

I also tried to write some Macros "call with" but its still not working

thanks everyone for your support.

Comment: no, a formula cannot "see" the color format of a cell.  are the other cells colored with conditional formatting?

Comment: What makes those cells "yellow"? Is it via conditional formatting? Or is the user setting the color? Or is it set by code?

Comment: What should be displayed in Cell J7 if Cell F7, Cell G7, and Cell H7 are all yellow?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without using VBA.
It is possible to create a UDF which uses `Cell.Interior.Color`, however, it will not recalculate upon changing colours.

I would strongly suggest finding another way to do what you want if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro, then run it against the filled cells. It will create a numerical value in the column to the left which you could then hide at the end of the macro.

```
Sub ListColors()

For Each c In Selection 

    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Interior.Color 

Next c 

End Sub
```

You could then run any formulas against that numerical value.

For full disclosure - found this info [here](https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/2035/do-something-based-on-cell-background-color-sumifs-if-countif-etc#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20cells%20with%20the,any%20conditional%20function%20or%20formula.)